# How to check for nested square brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, t-sql, sqlclr

I have the input string below:

```
[text1][text2][text3]...[textN]
```

and I want to apply the following validation rule using regular expression:

> The `]` and `[` cannot be included in other `[]`.

For example, the next input strings are not correct:

```
[test1][test2[][test3]
[test1][test2]][test3] 
[test1][test2[lol][test3]
[test1][test2]lol][test3]
```

I need to validate the input string because I am going to split it on `[]` groups (again using regular expression).

Comment: Does it have to use regular expressions?

Comment: I've done it before by counting, loop through the string, add 1 when you see [ and subtract 1 when you see ]. If the value is ever 2, its nested. It has other uses too, if you go through the whole string and the result isn't zero, then you have mismatched brackets.

Comment: @Derek I am doing this in the context of `T-SQL` using SQL CLR implementations of .net regular expression functions. It seems to be the fastest way to validate the input string there?

Comment: Is any text allowed _outside_ square brackets? Do you want to check on that, too?

Comment: And you might want to move that logic into c# or wherever the code is BEFORE you try to write it to the database.

Comment: Maybe something like `"\[[^\[\]]*\]*"` ?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, but I can do it after the first check, with separate regular expression.

Comment: Do you want to validate or get matches ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want a regexp here is a quick one :

`^(\[[^\[\]]+\])*$`

Works on your examples

The principle here is for each bracket pair `(\[.*\])*` to contain any text that does NOT contains a bracket `[^\[\]]+`

In case you need to be able to have `[test1][test2][][test3]` working change the `+` with an `*` to allow the empty string to match

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
^(\[\w*\])*$
```

It means

- ^ start with
- [ a `[`
- \w* multiple word characters (`\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)
- ] a `]`
- `*` multiple times
- $ end of string

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Numbers will work, but punctuation other than underscore wouldn't.  `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`